# How to add a scrollbar to tinker-gui tool?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a resume-parser from this link [here](https://github.com/0dust/ResumeFilter),

I've cloned it using,

> `git clone https://github.com/John-8704/ResumeFilter.git`

and then just execute:

> `python utils/create_training_data.py`

This just open the tinker GUI tool required for manually annotate data but it doesn't have a scroll bar to scroll through.

So I've edited that script i.e.,`create_training_data.py` in it I've modified the `resume_gui function` with below code to add scroll bar functionality but even then the scroll bar is not visible. How can I add scrollbar to it.

To reproduce, 
Just clone the repo and try running `python utils/create_training_data.py`

```
def resume_gui(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content):
    lines_with_dummy_labels = [[line, -1, -1] for line in file_content]

    master = Tk()
    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), 
                                         master.winfo_screenheight()))
    canvas = Canvas(master, width=170, height=300)
    vsb = Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)
    vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    gui = LabelResume(master, lines_with_dummy_labels)

    def callback():
        master.destroy()
        output_file_path = os.path.join(training_data_dir_path, str(index)+'.csv')
        if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
            return
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines_with_dummy_labels,columns=['text',
                                                                  'type','label'])
        rows_to_drop = data.loc[((data['type']== -1) | (data['label'] == -1))].index
        data.drop(data.index[rows_to_drop],inplace = True,axis = 0)
        data.to_csv(output_file_path,index = False)

    canvas.config(yscrollcommand= vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)
    gui.mainloop()
```

If someone can help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean, exactly?  I don't see where you're adding any content to the Canvas for it to scroll.

Comment: @jasonharper I mean the scrollbar is not visible. I'm not very familiar with tinker and I've put it together by following few tutorials online if you just clone and edit the `resume_gui` with above and then execute `python utils/create_training_data.py` the scrollbar will not be visible.

Comment: @stovfl I'm using windows pc and for me `scrollbar` is not visible. Does it have anything to do with screen resolution?  Have you used the above function in place of actual function from the original repo

Comment: @user_12 ***"Have you used the above function"***: Yes, but your example violate the [mcve] guidelines, i have to remove some parts. You are using `from tkinter import *`, note the `*`, which could lead to unexpeced behavior. [Edit] your example per the [mcve] guidelines and i will run it again.

Comment: @stovfl I've modified the example. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @user_12 ***"master = Tk()"***: The instance `master` is local, it seems you are using multiple `Tk()`. Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: @stovfl I'm not getting what you meant. I only have one tk() I'm really never worked with tinker I've only put it together using online tutorials. Can you provide a answer on how can I fix this and get scroll bar to work?

Comment: @user_12 ***"I only have one `tk()`"***: You claim so, then you should get ***`NameError: name 'master' is not defined`***. OK, **indent all**  statements so that they belong to the `local namespace` of `def resume_gui(...`.

Comment: @stovfl I've done it. Even now I'm not getting scroll bar.

Comment: Now i get `NameError: name 'LabelResume' is not defined`, [edit] your question and show `class LabelResume(...`?

Comment: @stovfl It's a lot of code to paste here. If you can just clone the repo it will all have the necessary classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `LabelResume` source, it is adding itself to the window (see line 31). If you comment this out, this behaviour will stop and you can then add the frame to your canvas. The code for the `resume_gui` is then very similar but I am adding the `LabelResume` frame to the canvas using `canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=N + W, window=gui)` and then ensuring that it is rendered before updating the canvas scrollregion using `gui.update()`.

```
def resume_gui(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content):
    lines_with_dummy_labels = [[line, -1, -1] for line in file_content]

    master = Tk()
    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.state('zoomed')
    canvas = Canvas(master, width=170, height=300)
    vsb = Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)
    vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    gui = LabelResume(master, lines_with_dummy_labels)

    def callback():
        master.destroy()
        output_file_path = os.path.join(training_data_dir_path, str(index)+'.csv')
        if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
            return
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lines_with_dummy_labels,columns = ['text','type','label'])
        rows_to_drop = data.loc[((data['type']== -1) | (data['label'] == -1))].index
        data.drop(data.index[rows_to_drop],inplace = True,axis = 0)
        data.to_csv(output_file_path,index = False)

    canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=N + W, window=gui)
    gui.update()
    canvas.config(yscrollcommand= vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)
    gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a scrollbar in your code, you're going to need to make a separate frame around the main contents of your webpage since you are using a grid format in order to layout your application.

**You can't use pack, grid or anything in the same Frame.**

Everything within the frame will use grid layout to display, whereas the frame itself will use the pack function to show the scrollbar.

```
frame = Frame(master)
frame.pack(anchor=CENTER) 
# relx/y makes sure it covers
# the whole area of the window.
```

Now instead of gridding the contents to `master`, grid it to the frame.

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
```

Use the code above in order to create a scrollbar that will go across your whole application vertically where `frame` is the wrapper around your contents.

After adding the following changes, your code should look a bit like this:

```
def resume_gui(training_data_dir_path, index, file_path, file_content):
    lines_with_dummy_labels = [[line, -1, -1] for line in file_content]

    master = Tk()

    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), 
                                         master.winfo_screenheight()))

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack(anchor=CENTER)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
    scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

    canvas = Canvas(frame, width=170, height=300)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    gui = LabelResume(frame, lines_with_dummy_labels)

    canvas.config(yscrollcommand= vsb.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you provide what changes I need to make in my code I've provided above.

Comment: Getting this error `_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-relx": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side`

Comment: try removing the relx and rely arguments. I might've gotten the grid and pack args mixed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209861/discussion-between-d19mc-and-user-12).